# Showing team's performance vs an individual's performance using sap webi

Tags: webi

I need to show team's performance vs an individual performance using sap webi linear gauge. The team's performance is a dynamic data which changes over time; each team member should use an input control to select their name, then, they can see the median of the days it took them to build a product. Now, my problem is how to show both of these measures on the chart, because, once input control is used, only data related to a specific person is shown in the report, how can I also show team's data?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

The key is to make a variable which disregards the input control filter and include that in your gauge. I created an example with based on the number of accounts for a branch.

[image]

I created a variable called **Number of Accounts No Filter** defined like this...

```
=NoFilter([Number of Accounts])
```

I set the **Actual Value** of my Linear Gauge to "Number of Accounts" and **Maximum Value** to my "Number of Accounts No Filter" variable.

[image]

Finally, I created my input control as usual. Now when I filter using that input control I can see both values.

[image]